# How can i pre compile JSP files?

Tags: jsp

I'm pre compiling jsp files using ant task. Problem is i don't want to generate java files for jsps which are included in other jsp file. For example B.jsp is included in A.jsp then B.jsp file automatically included in generated java file for A.jsp, so now i want to ignore generating java equivalent file for B.jsp.
Any help is much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop generating Java equivalent files for JSP files which are included in another JSP file. If you want to compile without errors you must remove Java files manually.